# Custom link abbreviations in properties treated as headlines

Tags: org-mode

I have an agenda file with todo tasks where each task (and its subtasks) have an associated workspace folder or file, somewhere I actually do the work. To keep things organized I want this to be an inheritable property of the task and I want to have an abbreviation for the root workspace folder, eg

```
#+LINK: workspace file:~/workspace/%s
* TODO Write book
   :PROPERTIES:
   :Work: [[workspace:subfolder/.]]
   :END:
```

The above link though is not followed with `org-open-at-point`, rather it thinks workspace:subfolder is a heading in the file and asks me to create it. Replacing the link with file:~/workspace/subfolder/. with or without square brackets works. Can I make my link abbreviation work as a property value?

Comment: I don't think so: according to the [draft syntax doc](https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-syntax.html#Node_Properties) `property drawers` contain `node properties` which have a name and a value - each one of those is a string (with some restrictions). In particular, the value is syntactically just a plain string, not a link. Also, take a look at the function `org-element-node-property-parser`: that's the implementation of the description in the doc.

Comment: Thanks @NickD , that looks a definite answer then. Do you want to answer it, with any ideas on my intention?

Comment: Sorry, I only have the negative answer to offer - I don't know of any Org mode mechanism to basically expand an abbreviation on demand. [Macros](https://orgmode.org/manual/Macro-Replacement.html#Macro-Replacement) are only expanded on export, the generic abbrev or dabbrev mechanisms that emacs offers are expanded on entry. So nothing worhwhile on the positive side - but somebody else might have some better ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to NickD, the link is of type node-property and link abbreviations are not made. I was able to `C-c C-o` on the link using a new link type

```
(defvar workspace-folder "~/workspace/moutsopoulosg")
(defun org-workspace-follow (path)
  (find-file (format "%s/%s" workspace-folder path)))
(org-link-set-parameters "workspace" :follow #'org-workspace-follow)
```

then `[[workspace:here]]` works everywhere.